# Can't manage to inizialize i18next correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, i18next

I've tried to use i18n to translate a website, but there is an issue.
I managed to translate almost everything except a index.js constants file.

I use this file to "automate" the creation of the website using mapping methods:

```
<ul className='list-none hidden sm:flex flex-row gap-10'>
 {navLinks.map((nav) => (
  <li
    key={nav.id}
    className={`${
   active === nav.title ? "text-white" : "text-secondary"
   } hover:text-white text-[18px] font-medium cursor-pointer`}
   onClick={() => setActive(nav.title)}
  >
   <a href={`#${nav.id}`}>{nav.title}</a>
  </li>
 ))}
</ul>
```

But when i try to use i18n it gets initialized always AFTER the exports of index.js, so all the strings coming from this file are null.
What can i do?

```
const navLinks = [
  {
    id: "about",
    title: i18n.t('navbar.about'), //Example
  },
  {
    id: "work",
    title: "Work",
  },
  {
    id: "contact",
    title: "Contact",
  },
];
```

Comment: Not familiar with [i18next](https://www.i18next.com/overview/getting-started), but I'd suggest two alternatives: **(1.)** Make sure `i18next.init()` is called before `const navLinks = ...`, or **(2.)** put the i18n identifier inside the navLinks, instead of the actual text, e.g. `{ id: "about", titleI18nId: 'navbar.about' }`, and resolve the text later, e.g. like `const translatedNavLinks = navLinks.map( resolveNavlinksTranslations )`.

Comment: @kca I've tried that without any result. I still managed to fix the problem without using i18n. 
Anyway, thanks for the reply 
: )